# Ajax request only posting part of the text

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, prototypejs

I have the following ajax script (prototype js) but it is only posting part of the text.

```
Selenium.prototype.doSaveCopyPaste = function(locator) {
 var element = this.page().findElement(locator);
 var text = jQuery(element).text();
 console.log(text);

var ajax = new Ajax.Request('http://copypaste.test', {
  method: 'post',
  parameters: 'report=' + text,
  processData: false,
   onSuccess: function(transport) {
    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
    alert("Success! \n\n" + response);
   },
   onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
 });
   console.log(ajax);
 }
```

when i output `text` in the console i get everything that is passed through `locator`, an example being

```
------------------------------------------------------------
<br>
 Header 1
<br>
------------------------------------------------------------
<br>
 Header 2
<br>
 Sub Heading: A Name
<br>
 Sub Heading 2: Another Name
<br>
Sub Heading 3: data here
<br>
etc etc for about 3000 characters
```

So I realise i dont have a string here and this could be why im having problems?.. so how could i send all the data to my PHP script..

```
if ($_POST['report']) {
  echo $_POST['report'];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode your string before you post it:

```
...
parameters: 'report=' + encodeURIComponent(text);
...
```

Now characters in your string can invalidate it, split it into multiple key - value fields, etc.

Comment: thank you so much, you have just ended a very long and head hitting the table debugging session :-)